# how many can we build a set of eigenbasis which describes arbitrary physical system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

Suppose Hamiltonian $H\phi = E\phi$.
we can choose eigenstates of Hamiltonian by finding operator $A$ which is $[A,H] = 0$.
Does it means that every operator which commutes with $H$ can have same eigenbasis set which describes any Physical system with Hamiltonian $H$?

I think there can be so many operators which commute with $H$.
For example, suppose harmonic oscillator.
we can consider x-basis, and p-basis. but why not $L$ (angular momentum) or $t$ (time) or etc. 
Please Help me. 
Thank you all.

Comment: I have no idea what you're really trying to ask. Yes, for every operator $A$ that commutes with $H$ there is an eigenbasis of $A$ that is also one of $H$ (this does *not* mean that *every* eigenvector of $A$ is one of $H$). What exactly is your question about that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Could you explain more about why every eigenvector of A is not the same of H even though [A,H] = 0. It would be grateful if you take an example.

Comment: And I thought that if we want to find a set of eigenbasis of Hamiltonian, first we have to  find operator A which commutes H. For example, hydrogen atom we find n, l, m basis by choosing appropriate operator. Am I wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: The identity commutes with everything, and every vector is an eigenvector of the identity, but clearly not every vector is an eigenvector of everything. And, well, yes, finding operators that commute with $H$ whose eigenvectors you already know is one way to get eigenvectors of $H$. Again, what is the *question* about that?

Comment: I think that's the point. Thanks. You're genius. Actually, I have been confused about how we can choose 'appropriate' operator to make 'appropriate' basis for physical system. and that's my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum mechanics describes the world according to complete sets of operators. An example are the position and momentum operators that obey the commutator $[\hat x, \hat p] = i\hbar$. Then as a result a Hamiltonian for a free particle $\hat H = \frac{1}{2m}\hat p^2$ has the commutator with the momentum operator
$$
[\hat p, \hat H] = \frac{1}{2m}[\hat p, \hat p^2] = 0
$$
and you have
$$
[\hat x, \hat H] = \frac{1}{2m}[\hat x, \hat p^2] = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\hat p
$$
This free Hamiltonian is in a commuting set of operators with the momentum operator.

To muddle this up some one can consider the Hamiltonian $\hat H = \frac{1}{2m}\hat p^2 + \frac{k}{2}\hat x^2$. This Hamiltonian is not in a complete set of commuting operators with either the momentum or position. This is a big motivation for switching to the lowering and raising operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ and the Hamiltonian as $\frac{1}{2}a^\dagger a$. This opens the door to a system that underlies Lie algebras of operators. The commutators
$$
[a, a^\dagger] = 1,~ [H, a] = a^\dagger,~ [H, a^\dagger] = a
$$
are an elementary case of roots and weight in Lie algebras.

Look in the third volume of Feynman's lectures on the kaon oscillation problem for an example of a Hamiltonian that is perturbed by another Hamiltonian that is not diagonalizable in the same basis.

Comment: Oh! you exactly pointed out what I am looking for! I would like to make clear one thing. Do you mean that there is a system which cannot be described in a complete set of eigenbasis?

Comment: This happens with the PMNS matrix for neutrinos and their mass. Neutrino oscillations are the result of symmetry breaking and the masses of neutrinos as weakly interacting particles. The symmetry breaking means this mass matrix is the physics on the low energy vacuum, but not of the full Lagrangian. The result is that a neutrino oscillates between the three types. The Feynman discussion of the kaon problem is a two state version of the same thing.

Comment: To continue ..., yes one can have Hamiltonians for a system that are perturbed or broken in symmetry so that it has terms that are not diagonalizable in the same basis. In particle physics we tend to use Lagrangians more frequently because in the complete sets of commuting operators the Hamiltonian approach is redundant; one only needs one commuting set! Nature at high energy may have a nice diagonalized basis, but on the low energy physical vacuum things become complicated.